# Change default pdf viewer in WSL2

Tags: pdf, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zathura

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 inside Windows 10. `xdg-open` currently opens something called `gv:` as the default pdf viewer. I would like to use zathura.  I couldn't find any `.desktop` files in the WSL2 environment. How do I change the default viewer for PDF files?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ubuntu Core 20 and not Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL2?   I didn't think the *snap* only releases were supported under WSL2.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: I meant Ubuntu 20.04. I didn't realize there was an Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Please correct your question... Ubuntu has had *snap* only products (using *yy* format unlike standard *deb* based releases that use *yy.mm* like 20.04) since 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make Zathura the default PDF viewer using the documentation [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zathura#Make_zathura_the_default_pdf_viewer).